# MATLAB How to get rid of loop for subtracting two arrays

Tags: arrays, algorithm, matlab, vector, vectorization

I am trying to subtract two arrays in MATLAB of different sizes and I am currently using a for loop, which takes a long amount of time.
Is there any way to make the code below faster? I'm wondering if maybe I can somehow create an array that is 117x489x489 in a fast way without the for loop.

The first array, a, has dimensions 1x117, the second array, b, has dimensions 489x489.
The result matrix  has dimensions 117x489x489.

Here is how I am subtracting the two arrays:

```
for i = 1:length(a)
  result(i) = a(i) - b;
end
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use efficient [`bsxfun`](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) here that avoids the loop by doing `expansions` of both `a` and `b` to a size of `117x489x489` and then performs `elementwise subtraction` under the hood. Thus, it presents a vectorized approach to achieve the desired result. Here's the code -

```
result = bsxfun(@minus,a(:),permute(b,[3 1 2]))
```

That `(:)` with `a` and [`permute`](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/permute.html) with `b` helps in creating `singleton dimensions` for `a` and `b` respectively as needed for their respective expansions with `bsxfun`.

---

You can avoid `permute` there with some [`reshaping`](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/reshape.html) like so -

```
result = reshape(bsxfun(@minus,a(:),b(:).'),[numel(a) size(b)])
```

Comment: Why would you want to avoid `permute`? Is permute a lot slower than `reshape`?

Comment: @kkuilla Yeah from my little experience with it, it's heavy specially when permuting large arrays and multidimensional arrays. In this case, `b` being `489x489`, it could be costly. If It were `a` instead with `1x117`, it won't be that big a deal though. `reshape` on the other hand is supposedly light on runtime cost.